# MAXIFS without fixed criteria

Tags: function, google-sheets

I need a formula that searches for matching criteria in column A and then calculates the MAX value of the matching values from column B. The number of criteria can be different.
In my example the criteria are the weeks, but it could also be text once.
I have tried the following formula but without success:
=MAXIFS(B2:B;A2:A;A=A)
I've tried MAXIF because in some cases there may be more than one column of criteria that need to be used for comparison.

[image]

Comment: Try `=ArrayFormula(MAXIFS($B$2:$B,Weeknum($A$2:$A),WEEKNUM(A2)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can get a mini report of the max values grouped by week like this:

`=query(A1:B, "select A, max(B) where A is not null group by A", 1)`

It is unclear why you would need to repeat the max value on every row, but if that is really necessary, you can use this formula in *row 2* of a free column:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      A2:A, 
      query(A2:B, "select A, max(B) group by A", 0), 
      2, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

This is an array formula that fills the whole column automatically.